# System.Net.Http.HttpClient adds Request-Id header

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, dotnet-httpclient

I noticed that when `HttpClient` is used in ASP.Net Core web api controller, it adds `Request-Id` header to the requests it sends. That does not happen when `HttpClient` is used in e.g. a .Net Core console app.

I presume this is done to implement correlation (or tracking) IDs, but how does it work? What exactly adds this header?

Also how can I remove it? I've implemented my own correlation IDs.

Comment: Application Insights?

Comment: @Tratcher thanks for pointing me in the right direction. Now as I knew what to google, I was able to find this: https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/disable-application-insights-correlation-id-headers-on-httpclient-requests-in-aspnet-core/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have stumbled across this problem when all requests issued by RestSharp were also containing `Request-Id`. The [solution mentioned in the comments](https://blog.wille-zone.de/post/disable-application-insights-correlation-id-headers-on-httpclient-requests-in-aspnet-core/) also worked for me and deserves to be promoted as an answer:

#### Startup.cs

```
private void DisableCorrelationIds(IServiceCollection services)
{
    var module = services.FirstOrDefault(t =>
        t.ImplementationFactory?.GetType() == typeof(Func<IServiceProvider, DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule>));
    if (module != null)
    {
        services.Remove(module);
        services.AddSingleton<ITelemetryModule>(provider => new DependencyTrackingTelemetryModule
        {
            SetComponentCorrelationHttpHeaders = false
        });
    }
}

public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // other stuff may come here
    DisableCorrelationIds(services);
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately this does not work in .NET Core 3.1
Anyone have idea as to why please?

Comment: @PKCS12 Did you try [this suggestion](https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/19044#issuecomment-586618046)? It is pretty recent and I guess it is for ASP.NET Core 3.1 or later.

Comment: I did indeed try that! It did not work :<